# Check windows authentication and if user in sql table, give access to mvc 5.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, windows-authentication

I am pretty new to ASP.net in general. Can someone please help me here.

Here is my scenario. 
I have a sql database where all the user details are mentioned who will get access to mvc web project. my development server url is delta.dcy.com

Whenever user tries to login this page, it should check windows authentication. once authenticated, it should check if user is in database. if yes, then access to the webpage should be given.

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this. i am having a very hard time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step Go to Web.Config
Add:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">

</authentication>
```

Then where ur Methods for SQL is

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Managers")]
        public ActionResult CompanySecrets()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Users="redmond\\swalther")]
        public ActionResult StephenSecrets()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

More info: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs